# Can't Connect to localhost:8088/cluster - YARN Resource Manager on Mac Catalina

Tags: macos, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Just installed Hadoop 3.2.2 on mac catalina and I can view the name node through localhost:9870 just fine, but when I sbin/start-yarn.sh  and try to view the YARN resource manager through localhost:8088 I get a "This site can’t be reached" page.

My 'yarn-site.xml' config reads as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>JAVA_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME,HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,CLASSPATH_PREPEND_DISTCACHE,HADOOP_YARN_HOME,HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME</value>
    </property>
    
</configuration>
```

Comment: `start-yarn` creates several log files for the ResourceManager and NodeManager. One of these shows your error, not the browser.

Comment: Switching from Java 17 to Java 8 is what helped solve this issue.